# In place tokenizing of a std::string

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

There are several possibilites to tokenize a std::string like strtok does it with C style strings. I found boost::tokenizer, getline, or a manual iteration through the string. But each of these possibilities differ from strtok because they all are not in place. They copy the characters to new strings (please correct me if one of my given possibility actually works different) while strtok doesn't need to allocate (at least from my view - internally it could possibly allocate memory) any memory.

Now I'm just curious if there is any way of realizing this behaviour for a std::string? I thought about accessing via [data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) but it returns a const pointer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Already answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I tried the wrong keywords.

Comment: no problem, it was your first post.

Comment: Today I found the time to try the possibilities given in the other question. As I already thought most of them didn't work in place. Only the C style strtok doesn't use any unnecessary allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tokenize a `std::string` in-place simply by yielding the tokes as pairs of `std::string` iterators.

Comment: Is there a way of representing a pair of string iterators as if they were real strings?

Comment: @user1678062: If you can live with creating a temporary copy of the string, then you could just use the `std::string` constructor taking two iterators.

Comment: Well, then I have to live with it or write my own string class. Nevertheless thanks for your answer!